# LINQ Syntax for querying a dictionary.ToList().Where()

Tags: linq

I am trying to get the correct syntax for my LINQ statement. I have a dictionary, and then a method that checks values in that dictionary. I am trying to count the messages to list where the values are not null or empty (they can be manipulated elsewhere)

```
    ScannerMessages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public enum ScanType { GoodScan, Reprint, BadScan, DiscernScanType}
    public ScanType equalMessages()
    {
        lock (lckObj)
        {
            int x = ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Distinct().Count();
            int y = ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Count;

            if (ScannerMessages.Values.All(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))) return ScanType.BadScan;
            else if (_ScannerCount == 1) return ScanType.DiscernScanType;
            else if (x < y) return ScanType.GoodScan;
            else if (ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Distinct().Where(x => x.Value != string.IsNullOrEmpty()).Count() == 1) return ScanType.Reprint;
            else return ScanType.BadScan;
        }
    }
```

it's this statement that is off

```
    ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Distinct().Where(x => x.Value != string.IsNullOrEmpty()).Count()
```

and I also tried on the list creation on both sides of the ToList() (but they're wrong too)

```
ScannerMessages.Values.Where(x => x.Value != string.IsNullOrEmpty()).ToList().Distinct().Count()
ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Where(x => x.Value != string.IsNullOrEmpty()).Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: You should probably also call Scanner.Messages.Values.ToList() once at the beginning of the function and reuse it throughout. This will keep it from being reenumerated with each call.

Comment: What's with the absolutely terrible repeated `.ToList()` calls on the same object? Three entire arrays created and instantly discarded and four full scans of the same array per function call, that's grounds for firing imo..

Comment: BenBartle, I don't need them in a list, just the count

@Blindy what are you talking about?! Can you really not see that was/is copy/pasted of same code so I could target the area I had a question on? and Then I call out clearly that the other two were failed attempts? AND! I'm comparing to an int- so coming off the count()... which is an int... not a list... so please read before flaming... of course it's created then discarded, I only want the count

Comment: ugh and now I can't edit comment- well again @Blindy I see what you are talking about thanks to Sergey explaining a little better below- Can you keep in mind that we are not all code gods and instead of flaming me you could have offered an explanation or alternative as he did. You are right though as I see what you and he were/are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ScannerMessages.Values.Distinct().Count(v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(v))
```

1. You already selected values, thus you already have sequence of strings, and you don't need to try getting value from string with `x.Value`
2. You should pass string to [`String.IsNulllOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to verify if this string is null or empty
3. You don't need to create list with value from dictionary - [`ValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x8bctb9c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<string>` thus you can use Linq methods directly (e.g. `Distinct` or `Where`)
4. If you want to count items in sequence which match some condition (i.e. predicate) then instead of usage `Where(predicate).Count()` you can use shortcut - overloaded [`Count(predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method which takes predicate.

Comment: This similar to other comment below by jwg pointed me towards the right path- The ToList() got dropped out, I'm assuming this will run accurately- thanks!  

    else if (ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Distinct().Count(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)) == 1) return ScanType.Reprint;

Comment: @alykins your code checks if there is exactly one unique non-empty value in dictionary. And don't forget to remove `ToList()` call :)

Comment: Yeah, it is supposed to check to see if there is one non-empty value. Wait... I need the ToList() call, don't I?
OH! I think I see it now- I don't need to send it to a list because I'm already picking the count from the values and I am expecting 1 so I can ignore sending it to a list in this case... right?

Comment: @alykins as I pointed in #3 you just don't need to save all values to list. That will create new array of strings in memory. But you don't need it. Why create copy, if you can query dictionary values directly?

Comment: Ok I see now- I can just query the values as they are query-able. I don't know why I had it written like that as in another section I query off Keys. and also right above that piece of code I have Value.All(...) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Value` property on `string`.`Values` property gives you a `ValueCollection` not a collection of `KeyValuePairs`. You just need:

```
ScannerMessages.Values.Distinct().Count(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Comment: No, it sends all the Dictionary< key, value> value fields to a list, and then I need to select from that list where they are not null or empty, the distinct count. so for example if I have three entries, "A":"123", "B":"123", "C":""|null I would need it to return count being 1. From my understanding what is posted above would return 2 correct?

Comment: @alykins yes it will return 2. do you need to count of null values, or non-null values ?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested but this part looks wrong:

```
x.Value != string.IsNullOrEmpty()
```

You are comparing the value of the item to the return value of the boolean function. You should be either testing the return value:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value)
```

or checking if the string is equal to something or other

```
x.Value != ""
```

or

```
x.Value != null
```

or some combination of the two.

Comment: Yes that was the part I was having issues with- it ended up being x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)

Comment: I saw from the other answers that you didn't need `x.Value` but I didn't see the point in adding it to the answer since the others are complete.